# Shortcuts Not working in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

Ubuntu 10.10 x64

Has been working fine since install last week, all of a sudden lost the ability to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> etc.

Seems to work fine in login screen, but once it boots up desktop the ability of shortcuts is gone. I'm pretty stuck without <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.

N.b. I can still <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+right click to open browser window in new tab.

Any thoughts?